# Is the limit of this integral zero?

Tags: limits

$\phi\big(x\mid x_0,1/N\big)$ is the density function of $N(x_0,1/N)$. If I know 
$$\int\phi\big(x\mid x_0,1/N\big)f(y,x)\,dx\,dy<\infty$$
and 
$$\int\phi\big(x\mid x_0,1/N\big)f(y,x_0)\,dx\,dy<\infty,$$ 
and I also know that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(y,x)=f(y,x_0).$$

Is the following true?

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\int \phi\bigg(x\mid x_0,1/N\bigg)\bigg|f(y,x)-f(y,x_0)\bigg|\,dx\,dy\rightarrow 0$$

Comment: Do you mean $\lim\limits_{N\to \infty \\ x\to x_0}...$ ?

Comment: I think as $N\rightarrow \infty$, $\phi(x|x_0,1/N)$ converges to a point mass on $x_0$. So yes, but implicitly.

Comment: I think I might have an answer. First the conditions are not enough for the limit to be true. I think we need some uniform integrity and then the limit can be obtained from generalized dominant convergence theorem. Will post an answer once I complete my proof. Doing it right now.